# Error installing Visual Studio for PowerShell on Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, vsix, sql-server-data-tools

Trying to install PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio on Windows Server 2012 I get an error:

> Signaturedescription cannot be created...

Is SQL Server Data Tools Visual Studio different from Power Shell Visual Studio in this regard? I have installed and using SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013 successfully. Can I use the same SSDT VS 2013 for PowerShell too?

Comment: Just in case, make sure you've downloaded PS tools for the correct version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm .I found a fix to my issue. I have installed the Visual Studio 2013 and I am trying to install PowerShell tools of 2015 Visual Studio. And for newbies like me -- Microsoft Visual Studio is one and PowerShell Tools can be added.For 2013 VS version download and Install 2013 PowerShell extension data tools only.Else you will get issues.Yes we can use same VS for MSBI and PowerShell too.